# Pull the string between two string in python which has multiple repeating same words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get string from text "20231006-OPUS solution _ cfhs0230.22d OP1696574785263-792.txt", I'm interested in "cfhs0230.22d", I used the below method but it doesn't work as there are two "OP" in it...so i want to skip first "OP" and take second "OP" instead and get string between "-" and second "OP", how can i do that?

```
mystr = "20231006-OPUS solution _ cfhs023 OP1696574785263-792"
sub1 = "-"
sub2 = "OP"  #this has to be second OP
idx1 = mystr.index(sub1)
idx2 = mystr .index(sub2)
print(idx1+ len(sub1) + 1,idx2)
for nx in range(idx1+ len(sub1) + 1,idx2):
    print(nx)
```

Comment: I just wanted to mention, that you should not use `str` as a variable name as that shadows the built-in class and will probably break other code down the line.

Comment: Is there always a space before the second "OP"? Then you could include that in the matching string.

Comment: @Raphael yes there is always space before second OP

Answer (score 4):

You can use that spaces between string for string and that will provide you string that want and in str() function you can print that string as well.

```
str = '20231006-OPUS solution _ cfhs023 OP1696574785263-792'
sub1 = "_ "
sub2 = " OP"  #this has to be second OP
idx1 = str.index(sub1)
idx2 = str.index(sub2)
print(str[idx1+2:idx2])
print(idx1 + 2,idx2)
for nx in range(idx1 + 2,idx2):
    print(nx)
```

Comment: Note that you should not shadow the name `str`.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into a list of 5 "words", then take the word at index 3:

```
words = str.split()
print(words[3])
```

If there are a number of strings that you want to parse, it really depends upon whether they fit a pattern or not. Do they always contain 5 words separated by spaces? Is the word at index 3 always the target word? To address things like this would require more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add argument to the index method started from the index of first substring (`idx1`):

```
string = '20231006-OPUS solution _ cfhs023 OP1696574785263-792'
sub1 = "_"
sub2 = "OP"  #this has to be second OP
idx1 = string.index(sub1)
idx2 = string.index(sub2, idx1) # idx1 as start parameter
print(idx1+ len(sub1) + 1,idx2)
for nx in range(idx1+ len(sub1) + 1,idx2):
    print(nx)

print(string[idx1+ len(sub1) + 1:idx2])
```